# append in middle of NSString in iPhone programming

Tags: iphone, nsstring

how to append the value of string in between NSString?

for example:

```
NSString* str1 = @"Hello";

NSString* str2 = @"Hi.."/*add contents of str1*/@"how r u??";
```

please tell me how to achieve this??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Append always means add to the end. That's inserting a string in the middle.)

If you simply want to construct a literal string, use

```
#define STR1 @"Hello"
NSString* str2 = @"Hi..." STR1 @" how r u??";
```

To insert it in run time you need to convert str2 into a mutable string and call `-insertString:atIndex:`.

```
NSMutableString* mstr2 = [str2 mutableCopy];
[mstr2 insertString:str1 atIndex:4];
return [mstr2 autorelease];
```

Answer (score 7):

There are multiple answers possible. It depends a bit on how you want to figure out where to insert the text. One possibility is:

```
NSString *outStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:"%@%@%@", [str2 substringToIndex:?], str1, [str2 substringFromIndex:?]];
```

Comment: Great answer. Small typo in the answer though: subStringToIndex/subStringFromIndex should be substringToIndex/substringFromIndex (the word "String" isn't capitalized)